# Linux secure file sharing without ssh login access

Tags: linux, network-share

I'm looking for a way to make a directory on a linux system available for reading to other linux and windows clients. The share must require some authentication from the client and the passwords and files must be sent encrypted.

The clients should only be able to access the shared directory by some protocol, but NOT be able to log in via ssh. If I'm not mistaken that rules out sftp, scp and samba.

Is there a way to achieve this by some other file sharing technique or settings or do I need to have a linux user that can also do ssh login?

If I need a user who can ssh, I have found

https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users

but would prefer not to have the user at all, or block it from logging in.

Comment: Scponly is one tool you you cold use. Some ftp daemons allow virtual users and can use sftp/ftps.

Comment: You want to require authentication, but don't want to have a user... that's not going to work.

Comment: @lain this looks exactly like what I need for linux clients, thanks

Comment: if you want to share files with Linux and Windows clients your best option is probably `WebDAV` or `Samba`.Both support authentication and don't require special clients. I would go with setting up an Apache httpd to act as an WebDAV server.

Comment: @knowhy Thanks, I've decided to use WebDAV with SSL. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `WebDAV` protocol is probably the best option for this requirement. You can setup `Apache httpd` to act as an `WebDAV` server. `WebDAV` is a good solution for this requirement because Apache server is flexible when it comes to authentication and `WebDAV` does not need any special ports opened.

You can consult [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-webdav-access-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) for instructions how to setup Apache as an WebDAV server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Sync](https://www.getsync.com/) by BitTorrent.
It's based on Pear to Pear communication and is super fast.

Comment: Thanks, I might use that for windows clients. The free version is limited though, so I'll wait a bit if there are other options

Comment: I prefer Oranges to Pears ;-) ;-) ;-)